How do I use MSAL-react to get the oid of any user?
I'm new to MSAL and working on an Office js react add-in, which will be free to download and use with 'basic' features and require a subscription for 'pro' features. The subscription-purchase workflow will ultimately give me a database of subscribed users, by oid.
In my add-in, I need to get the oid of the logged-in user (which could be any Office user, personal, work or school), so I can check it against the list of subscribers and show/hide the 'Pro' features. The MSAL tutorial ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial works great for me, but only if I login with an Id known/guested to my tenant.
The example itself says "This sample will not work with a personal Microsoft account.", so what do I need to change for it to do so?
I have changed my Azure application to have "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount", but when I try to log in with a personal MS account, I get the account Id prompt, but then an error that the redirect-uri is not one I've listed for the app. Indeed, it isn't; the registered app redirect is "http://localhost:3000/" but the URL in the login prompt goes to:
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=51483342-085c-4d86-bf88-cf50c7252078&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2foffaddins.ciamlogin.com%2fcommon%2ffederation%2foauth2msa...
How do I just get the oid of whoever is signed in (if they're already signed in to MS in their browser), or pop up a sign-in prompt if they're not?

@S Bullen Check my answer with js using msal.

@DasariKamali, thanks for the sample, which works fine if the person is known to my tenant. I need a way for anyone to be able to login. If I try an account not known to my tenant, I get:
AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxx' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'yyyyy' and cannot access the application 'zzzz'(app name) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

You need to set up a Customer Tenant, with sign in and sign up userflow configured.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
